# Contour integration: $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

A problem from a complex analysis qualifier:

> Find $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$

**My answer so far:** We want to integrate the function $$f(z) = \frac{\cos z}{\sqrt{z}}dx = e^{iz-\frac12 \log z} + e^{-iz-\frac12 \log z}$$ for a branch of $\log$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:* $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt x}dx=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos t^2}tt\cdot dt=2\,\Re\int_0^\infty e^{it^2}dt\ -$ [Can](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) you take it from here ? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: this 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos{(x^2)}dx=2\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Comment: The answer should be $\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}$